# Using an array to populate multiple fields with MVC/C#

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

Searching through the site I see a lot of variations of this question, but none of them relate to this particular case.

I am trying to populate multiple DropDownLists with the value at `index i` from an array which holds strings within my model.

My template is similar (simplified) to the following:

```
@model foo

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ArrayName.Length; i++ )
{
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ArrayName[i], "Index " + i, new {})
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ArrayName[i], Model.ListOfPotentialValues, new {})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ArrayName[i])
}
```

To be more clear, `ArrayName` is a string array (`string[]`), `ListOfPotentialValues` is of the type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

The code for the model may be seen below:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfPotentialValues
{
    return SelectList(/* A list of Strings*/)
}

public string[] ArrayName { get; set; }

//Constructor
public foo()
{
    ArrayName = new string[] {"Foo", "Foo", "Baz","Qux"};
}
```

The view sends the following HTML output for the first dropdown (which is consistent for all of them)

```
<div>
    <label for="ArrayName_0_">Index 0</label>
    <select id="ArrayName_0_" name="ArrayName[0]">
        <option>Foo</option>
        <option>Bar</option>
        <option>Baz</option>
        <option>Qux</option>
    </select>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ArrayName[0]" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

From this, you may or may not have derived that `ArrayName` is, of course, the name of the array holding the values I want displayed and `ListOfPotentialValues` is a `SelectList` of values which may be selected. The list of values is showing up, but not setting its value as it would if I were to not use an array.

While the value for the dropdown does not populate, I am able to display the value of it if I call `@Model.ArrayName[i]` within my MVC Template.

More detail: 
If `ListOfPotentialValues` contains the values `Foo, Bar, Baz, Qux`
And `ArrayName` contains the values `Foo, Foo, Qux, Baz`

I would expect the dropdowns to start with the values Foo, Foo, Qux, Baz (respectively) while still having the option to select Foo, Bar, Baz, and Qux

Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: What is the type of `ArrayName`? `ListOfPotentialValues`? Can you provide a sample of the HTML that is being output?

Comment: I believe that this edit satisfies what you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this wont work - the `DropDownListFor()` works a little differently from the other helpers when used in a loop (its been raised as an issue on CodePlex a few times and I'm not sure if its a bug or just a limitation of the helper).

You need either a custom `EditorTemplate` for you model and pass the `SelectList` to the template as additional view data (but that not appropriate in your case since you only have an array of value types) or you need to construct a new `SelectList` in each iteration and use the overload that sets the `Selected` value. For example, you model needs a property which is a collection of objects (not a `SelectList`)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ArrayName[i], new SelectList(Model.MyCollection, "yourValueProperty", "yourTextProperty", Model.ArrayName[i])
```

Comment: This answer does a better job at explaining _what_ is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are using the `SelectList` is problematic, try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ArrayName[i], new SelectList(list, null, null, Model.ArrayName[i]), new {})
```

Not sure it will work with a list of strings, you may need to convert those to C# objects.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/701424/Default-value-for-html-DropdownListFor-in-MVC-Razo

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. In the question I state _The list of values is showing up, but not setting its value as it would if I were to not use an array_. This is to say, the fields were populating before I used the `string[]`. When I moved to an array version, the problem started.